# How to save all my Treeview's data and also specific data in different Excel files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to save my treeview's data in different Excel files, actually my code is working UPDATING my data in the same Excel file every time I want to save it, so What I want is to save in different files. I mean when I push my save button it shows 'where I want to save it in my computer' also 'what name to give that file', then just show a message 'saved successfully' or just 'You didn't select any data for saving'. This is my code which is saving the data in the same file:

```
def save():
    cols = ['ID CARD','NAME','SURNAME', 'DATE']
    path = 'read.csv'
    excel_name = 'newfile.xlsx'
    lst = []
    with open(path, "w", newline='') as myfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
        for row_id in mytree.get_children():
            row = mytree.item(row_id,'values')
            lst.append(row)
        lst = list(map(list,lst))
        lst.insert(0,cols)
        for row in lst:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_name)
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    df.to_excel(writer,'sheetname')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Seems like you need to loop through for the number of files you wish to create. There are lots of q & a on here about loops and looping with vba so use the structure to edit your code.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks man, I'll search more about that.

Comment: @CoolCloud I've edited buddy. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldnt be so hard to do this, you have to use `filedialog` from `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
```

and then replace `excel_name` with:

```
excel_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save location',defaultextension=[('Excel','*.xlsx')],filetypes=[('Excel','*.xlsx')])
```

This should bring up a file dialog asking you a location to save the file, after which the logic saves the file on the returned location. You can make this more better with `messagebox`, like:

```
excel_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title='Save location',defaultextension=[('Excel','*.xlsx')],filetypes=[('Excel','*.xlsx')]) 

if not excel_name or excel_name == '/': # If the user closes the dialog without choosing location
    messagebox.showerror('Error','Choose a location to save')
    return # Stop the function
```

Though I am not sure on if `excel_name` will be `''` or `'/'` everytime the user closes, use `print(excel_name)` and close the box and then make the `if` with whatever is printed out.

More about filedialog with tkinter: [Tkinter Dialogs — Python 3.9.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html)

Comment: Hey mate, I also got a similar code as yours, I just didn't know how to place it in my function and I was getting errors, Now I understand better the solution. Thank you